# PHP MVC FOREACH display

Tags: php, foreach

i struggling with forloop in MVC.
i want to pass data from input text where in data is equivalent to 1,2,3,4,5,6,7...... -that is from database.

i pass it to controller and get the data using $_POST method with name text1.
here is my controller code

```
    {
        $template = $this->loadView('view_display');
        if(isset($_POST['check'])):
            $text1= $_POST['text1'];
            $text1= explode(',', $text1);
            foreach($text1 as $text1):
            $rem = $this->Faculty_model->testFunction($this->security_plugin->cleanInput($text1));
            $template->set(['stud' => $rem, 'username' => $this->session_helper->get('username'), 'security'=> $this->security_plugin, 'url' => $this->url_helper]);
            endforeach;
        endif;
        $this->security_plugin->CSRFToken();
        $template->render();
```

here is my model

```
    {
        $sql="select * from table where id=:text1";
        $bind = array(
            ':text1' => $text1
        );
        $data = $this->db->fetchAll($sql, $bind);
        return $data;
    }
```

and this is my view

```
<?php if(!empty($stud)): ?>
<?php foreach($stud as $stud): ?>
<?php echo $security->SanitizeString($stud->ID); ?>
<?php echo $security->SanitizeString($stud->NAME); ?>
<?php echo $security->SanitizeString($stud->AGE); ?>
```

The problem is it will only display the last number from text1 textbox. i cant figure it out.

anyhelp is appreciated :)

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with MVC,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You need to define `$rem` as an array before `foreach()` and then do assignment of values.

2.Put `$template->set()` code outside of `foreach()`

```
$template = $this->loadView('view_display');
if(isset($_POST['check'])):
    $text1= $_POST['text1'];
    $text1= explode(',', $text1);
    $rem = [];
    foreach($text1 as $text1):
    $rem[] = $this->Faculty_model->testFunction($this->security_plugin->cleanInput($text1));
    endforeach;
    $template->set(['stud' => $rem, 'username' => $this->session_helper->get('username'), 'security'=> $this->security_plugin, 'url' => $this->url_helper]);
endif;

$this->security_plugin->CSRFToken();
$template->render();
```